Is a random matrix over a finite field have the largest expected rank?
Does a completely randomized matrix over a finite field have larger expected rank than other imperfect random matrices? (If this statement is vague, could you clarify this point with respect to the matrices A and B that I have given?)For example, can you compare a randomized m$\times$n matrix A compare to a following m$\times$n matrix B over $F_2$ of their expect rank?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & a_2 &  \cdots& a_n\\
a_2 & a_3 &  \cdots& a_{n+1}\\
 \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_m  & a_{m+1} 
&  \cdots &a_{m+n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$which $a_i$ is randomly chosen. Intuitively, there is some correlation between the row (column) vectors of matrix B, and it seems that the row (column) vectors of A have the best independence from each other. But I don't know how to explain this intuition.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@José Carlos Santos Thanks for the reminder, I've corrected it.

What do you mean by "other imperfect random matrices"? What are you comparing against?

@Matthew Spam Thanks, I don't know how to express “other imperfect random matrices” well, but I think the matrix B I given is an example, which $a_i$ is random, but vectors of matrix B has somewhat correlation. If this statement is vague, could you clarify this point with respect to the matrices A and B that I have given? And what I'm comparing against is the mathematical expectation of the rank of a matrix, I think the completely randomized matrix A will have the largest expect rank.

@ Ji Li So if I understand it well, you are asking about the influence of correlation between matrix elements on the expected rank of a matrix with random elements from a finite field? From the question it was not clear to me what even the difference was between $A$ and $B$.

@Matthew Spam Yes, thank you for the correction.
